# Symfony2 / Similar routes

Tags: symfony, routes

I have similar routes, symfony2 call second route(subcategory), if i type somethinkg like "example.com/cars/insert/.

```
web_portal_category:
path:     /{category}/
defaults: { _controller: WebPortalBundle:Default:category }

web_portal_subcategory:
path:     /{category}/{subcategory}/
defaults: { _controller: WebPortalBundle:Default:subcategory }

web_portal_insert:
path:     /{category}/insert/
defaults: { _controller: WebPortalBundle:Default:upload }
```

How can I force them to call right one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. Symfony reads te routes from top to bottom and takes the first route that matches. In your example the url ***cars/insert/*** matches with the second and the third route. Because the second route has only variables **{category}** & **{subcategory}** all the urls **x/y/** will match and the third route will never be reached.

if you swap the second and the third route like this than things will change.

```
web_portal_category:
path:     /{category}/
defaults: { _controller: WebPortalBundle:Default:category }

web_portal_insert:
path:     /{category}/insert/
defaults: { _controller: WebPortalBundle:Default:upload }

web_portal_subcategory:
path:     /{category}/{subcategory}/
defaults: { _controller: WebPortalBundle:Default:subcategory }
```

In this case only the **/x/insert** url will match the second route and all others will continue with the third route in the row.

Comment: You could also use `requirements: subcategory: "^((?!insert).*)$"` (match everything but "insert") in `web_portal_subcategory` but it would overcomplicate things in a really unnecessary way.

Answer (score 1):

You put them in the right order, because as soon as it finds a match, the routing component will stop and execute that action:

```
web_portal_insert:
path:     /{category}/insert/
defaults: { _controller: WebPortalBundle:Default:upload }

web_portal_subcategory:
path:     /{category}/{subcategory}/
defaults: { _controller: WebPortalBundle:Default:subcategory }

web_portal_category:
path:     /{category}/
defaults: { _controller: WebPortalBundle:Default:category }
```